# DomDocument php extract info and images

Tags: php, dom, extract, domdocument, text-extraction

Hello I am having a problem with DomDocument. I need to do an script which extracts all the information from the tables with certain id.

So I did:

```
$link = "WEBSITE URL";

$html = file_get_contents($link);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$context_nodes = $xpath->query('//table[@id="news"]/tr[position()>0]/td');
```

So I get all the `<td>`s and information, but the problem is that the `<img>` tags haven't been extracted by the script. How can I extract all the information of the tables either text or image html tags?

The html code from which I want to extract the info is:

```
<table id="news" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td width="539" height="35"><span><strong>Info to Extract</strong></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="35" class="texto10">Martes, 02 de Octubre de 2012  | Autor: Trovert"  rel="author"></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="35" class="texto12Gris"><p><strong>Info To extract</strong></p>
            <p><strong>&nbsp;</strong></p>
            <p><strong>Casa de Gobierno: (a 9 cuadras del hostel)</strong></p>
            <img title="title" src="../images/theimage.jpg" width="400" height="266" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is how I am iterating the extracted elements:

```
foreach ($context_nodes as $node) {
    echo $node->nodeValue . '<br/>';
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you please provide a minimum sample HTML and demonstrate what you want to extract?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, here there is some html code:

Comment: And? You already have a working code that get references to all desired `<td>`s, just iterate [their `childNodes`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php) to walk to whatever node you want.

Comment: I do that, but the <imgs are not coming with the information, just the texts. Any ideas?

Comment: Please demonstrate how you were trying to extract the `<img>`s.

Comment: Passerby thanks for your time; I just posted on the main message the iteration.

Comment: You'll have to try harder than just `nodeValue`/`textContent`. Check [the PHP document](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php) to see what API you can use to get the work done.

Answer (score 0):

If you need more than text, you'll have to try harder, not just `nodeValue`/`textContent`, but walk through the target nodes DOM branch:

```
function walkNode($node)
{
    $str="";
    if($node->nodeType==XML_TEXT_NODE)
    {
        $str.=$node->nodeValue;
    }
    elseif(strtolower($node->nodeName)=="img")
    {
        /* This is just a demonstration;
         * You'll have to extract the info in the way you want
         * */
        $str.='<img src="'.$node->attributes->getNamedItem("src")->nodeValue.'" />';
    }
    if($node->firstChild) $str.=walkNode($node->firstChild);
    if($node->nextSibling) $str.=walkNode($node->nextSibling);
    return $str;
}
```

This is a simple, straightforward recursive function. So now you can do this:

```
$dom=new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath=new DOMXPath($dom);
$tds=$xpath->query('//table[@id="news"]//tr[position()>0]/td');
foreach($tds as $td)
{
    echo walkNode($td->firstChild);
    echo "\n";
}
```

[**Online demo**](http://3v4l.org/mIZer)
(Please be noted that I "fixed" a little bit of your HTML as it doesn't seem valid; also pretty-indented a little bit)

This outputs something like this:

```
Info to Extract
Martes, 02 de Octubre de 2012  | Autor: Trovert
Info To extract

            Casa de Gobierno: (a 9 cuadras del hostel)
            <img src="../images/theimage.jpg" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually this works, but it deletes all the tags like <strong> <b>, etc. How can I extract all the tags as well? Thanks

Comment: @Gonzalo Then you'll have to be more clear on what you actually want. Your question only said that you want "information" (which is only text by your code) plus `<img>` tag, so that's what I do. Did you mean you want the "`innerHTML`" part of `<td>`s?

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
foreach ($context_nodes as $node) {
echo $doc->saveHTML($node) . '<br/>';
}
```